# Firebase throws no setter/field for photo_url found in class models.Post$Photo

Tags: android, firebase

Testing the new Google Firebase and i am getting this error when displaying data from the firebase realtime database. See error below.

```
06-09 22:23:05.335 28373-28373/appsng.com.pappaz V/BitmapFactory: DecodeImagePath(decodeResourceStream3) : res/mipmap-mdpi-v4/avatar.jpg
    06-09 22:23:05.375 28373-28373/appsng.com.pappaz V/BitmapFactory: DecodeImagePath(decodeResourceStream3) : res/mipmap-mdpi-v4/thumb_up.png
    06-09 22:23:05.380 28373-28373/appsng.com.pappaz V/BitmapFactory: DecodeImagePath(decodeResourceStream3) : res/mipmap-mdpi-v4/message.png
    06-09 22:23:05.390 28373-28373/appsng.com.pappaz W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for photo_url found on class models.Post$Photo
    06-09 22:23:05.390 28373-28373/appsng.com.pappaz W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for photo_url found on class models.Post$Photo
    06-09 22:23:05.390 28373-28373/appsng.com.pappaz W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for photo_url found on class models.Post$Photo
    06-09 22:23:05.390 28373-28373/appsng.com.pappaz W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for photo_url found on class models.Post$Photo
    06-09 22:23:05.395 28373-28373/appsng.com.pappaz V/BitmapFactory: DecodeImagePath(decodeResourceStream3) : res/mipmap-mdpi-v4/clear.png
    06-09 22:23:05.400 28373-28373/appsng.com.pappaz D/data: null
    06-09 22:23:05.400 28373-28373/appsng.com.pappaz V/BitmapFactory: DecodeImagePath(decodeResourceStream3) : res/mipmap-hdpi-v4/no_image_square.png
    06-09 22:23:05.415 28373-28373/appsng.com.pappaz D/data: null
    06-09 22:23:05.415 28373-28373/appsng.com.pappaz D/data: null
    06-09 22:23:05.420 28373-28373/appsng.com.pappaz D/data: null
    06-09 22:23:05.450 28373-28540/appsng.com.pappaz I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
    06-09 22:23:05.450 28373-28540/appsng.com.pappaz I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isShipBuild true
    06-09 22:23:05.450 28373-28540/appsng.com.pappaz I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Thread-12056-119902642: SmartBonding Enabling is false, SHIP_BUILD is true, log to file is false, DBG is false
    06-09 22:23:05.450 28373-28540/appsng.com.pappaz I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
    06-09 22:23:05.465 28373-28373/appsng.com.pappaz W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for photo_url found on class models.Post$Photo
    06-09 22:23:05.470 28373-28540/appsng.com.pappaz I/System.out: KnoxVpnUidStorageknoxVpnSupported API value returned is false
    06-09 22:23:05.470 28373-28373/appsng.com.pappaz D/data: null
    06-09 22:23:05.590 28373-28373/appsng.com.pappaz I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@1cf1f8b7 time:10585179
    06-09 22:23:10.090 28373-28413/appsng.com.pappaz V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from AppMeasurementService
```

And it seems to be coming from my model class. See my model Post class below

```
package models;

import com.google.firebase.database.Exclude;
import com.google.firebase.database.IgnoreExtraProperties;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;


public class Post implements Serializable{

    public String id,user_id,user_name,content,created,likes,user_photo;
    ArrayList<Photo> photos = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Comment> comments = new ArrayList<>();

    public Post(){

    }

    public Post(String id,String user_id,String user_name,String content,String created,String likes,String user_photo){
        this.id = id;
        this.user_id = user_id;
        this.user_name = user_name;
        this.content = content;
        this.created = created;
        this.likes = likes;
        this.user_photo = user_photo;
    }


    @Exclude
    public Map<String, Object> toMap() {
        HashMap<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();
        result.put("user_id", user_id);
        result.put("user_name", user_name);
        result.put("content", content);
        result.put("created", created);
        result.put("likes", likes);
        result.put("user_photo", user_photo);

        return result;
    }


    public ArrayList<Comment> getComments() {
        return comments;
    }

    public ArrayList<Photo> getPhotos() {
        return photos;
    }
    //// getters ////

    public String getId(){
        return this.id;
    }

    public String getUser_id(){
        return this.user_id;
    }

    public String getUser_name(){
        return this.user_name;
    }

    public String getUser_photo(){
        return this.user_photo;
    }

    public String getContent(){
        return this.content;
    }

    public String getCreated(){
        return this.created;
    }

    public String getLikes(){
        return this.likes;
    }

    //// setters ////

    public void setComments(ArrayList<Comment> value){
        this.comments = value;
    }

    public void setPhotos(ArrayList<Photo> value){
        this.photos = value;
    }


    public void setId(String value){
        this.id = value;
    }

    public void setUser_id(String value){
        this.user_id = value;
    }

    public void setUser_name(String value){
        this.user_name = value;
    }

    public void setUser_photo(String value){
        this.user_photo = value;
    }

    public void setContent(String value){
        this.content = value;
    }

    public void setCreated(String value){
        this.created = value;
    }

    public void setLikes(String value){
        this.likes = value;
    }



    public String toString(){
        return this.user_id;
    }

    public static class Photo implements Serializable{

        String photo_url;

        public Photo(){

        }

        public Photo(String photo_url){
            this.photo_url = photo_url;
        }

        public String getPhotoUrl(){
            return photo_url;
        }

        public void setPhotoUrl(String photo_url){
            this.photo_url = photo_url;
        }

        public String toString(){
            return this.photo_url;
        }

    }




    public static class Comment implements Serializable{

        public String id,user_id,user_name,user_photo,timestamp,content;

        public Comment(){

        }

        public Comment(String id,String user_id,String user_name,String user_photo,String timestamp,String content){
            this.id = id;
            this.user_id = user_id;
            this.user_name = user_name;
            this.user_photo = user_photo;
            this.timestamp = timestamp;
            this.content = content;
        }

        @Exclude
        public Map<String, Object> toMap() {
            HashMap<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();
            result.put("id", id);
            result.put("user_id", user_id);
            result.put("user_name", user_name);
            result.put("user_photo", user_photo);
            result.put("timestamp", timestamp);
            result.put("content", content);
            return result;
        }



        //// getters ////
        public String getId(){
            return this.id;
        }

        public String getUser_id(){
            return this.user_id;
        }

        public String getUser_name(){
            return this.user_name;
        }

        public String getUser_photo(){
            return this.user_photo;
        }

        public String getTimestamp(){
            return this.timestamp;
        }

        public String getContent(){
            return this.content;
        }

        //// setters ////

        public void setId(String value){
            this.id = value;
        }

        public void setUser_id(String value){
            this.user_id = value;
        }

        public void setUser_name(String value){
            this.user_name = value;
        }

        public void setUser_photo(String value){
            this.user_photo = value;
        }

        public void setTimestamp(String value){
            this.timestamp = value;
        }

        public void setContent(String value){
            this.content = value;
        }



        public String toString(){
            return this.id;
        }

    }
```

Comment: move your static classes outside the public class.